# RDLC (VS 2010) How to access nested class or arrays on DataObjects

Tags: .net, reporting, rdlc

How can I access the TD.SubNumber property and Numbers[] on RDLC? I keep getting #Error on my expressions "=Fields!TD.Value.SubNumber" and "=Fields!Numbers.Value(0)".

```
public class TestData
{

    TestSubData tdata = new TestSubData();
    public TestSubData TD
    {
        get { return tdata; }
        set { tdata = value; }
    }

    string m_Description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return m_Description; }
        set { m_Description = value; }
    }

    int[] m_Numbers = new int[12];
    public int?[] Numbers
    {
        get { return m_Numbers; }
    }


}
public class TestSubData
{
    int x;
    public TestSubData()
    { 
    }

    public int SubNumber
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar discussion and some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180118/rdlc-filtering-nested-tables/2918376#2918376

Answer (score 1):

Add the "serializable" attribute to each of the nested classes, then you can reference with expressions such as:

"=Fields!TD.Value.SubNumber"

```
[Serializable()]
public class TestData
{
    TestSubData tdata = new TestSubData();
    public TestSubData TD
    {
        get { return tdata; }
        set { tdata = value; }
    }

    string m_Description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return m_Description; }
        set { m_Description = value; }
    }

    int[] m_Numbers = new int[12];
    public int?[] Numbers
    {
        get { return m_Numbers; }
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class TestSubData
{
    int x;
    public TestSubData()
    { 
    }

    public int SubNumber
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
}
```